# Converting a WSDL file into XSD file in java

Tags: java, web-services

Hi I want to convert a given WSDL file into a XML schema programatically. I need the schema for validating my SOAP responses against it. Can anyone help me with the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add an example of what you want to do would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This only makes sense if you tell more about what you want to DO with the schema.

Comment: Hi I have changed the question, to help you understand the context better.. can you help me now????